# How to use beautifulsoup to get node text and children tag separately

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My html is like:

```
<a class="title" href="">
    <b>name 
    <span class="c-gray">position</span>
    </b>
</a>
```

I want to get name and position string separately. So my script is like:

```
lia = soup.find('a',attrs={'class':'title'})
pos = lia.find('span').get_text()
lia.find('span').replace_with('')
name = lia.get_text()
print name.strip()+','+pos
```

Although it can do the job, I don't think is a beautiful way. Any brighter idea?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.contents` method this way:

```
person = lia.find('b').contents
name = person[0].strip()
position = person[1].text
```

Comment: alright~ I just so lazy to read the document, only know get_text(), shame

Comment: @milowang `.text()` and `.get_text()` are the same

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to locate the `a` element, then, for the `name` - get the first text node from an inner `b` element and, for the `position` - get the `span` element's text:

```
>>> a = soup.find("a", class_="title")
>>> name, position = a.b.find(text=True).strip(), a.b.span.get_text(strip=True)
>>> name, position
(u'name', u'position')
```